# Avoid url escaping in links

Tags: url, cakephp, pagination, hyperlink

I had to make my custom pagination helper in CakePHP because the one that cake provides didn't suit my needs. Still, everything was fine about the data retrieval and per-page grouping, but now when I want to generate the links on the bottom of the page (say, `< previous`, `next >` and the numbering), I can't make the links work as intended.

I found that the problem is the `HtmlHelper` escaping the `href` portion of the links, so when I generate a link via `$this->Html->link()` like:

```
$this->Html->link('Next >',array('controller' => 'topic','action' => 'list','page:2'));
```

It outputs:

```
<a href="http://exam.ple/topic/list/page%3A2">Next &gt;</a>
```

Putting `escape = false` as an option didn't work either.

So is there a way to avoid escaping the url in links in HtmlHelper?

Comment: How did you try escape=>false? Please show the code. Because that is (the documented) way of doing this actually. Also documented is how you properly use named params.

Comment: `didn't suit my needs` - how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$this->Html->link('Next >', 
    array('controller' => 'topic', 'action' => 'list', 'page' => '2'), 
    array('escape' => false));
```

Named params need to be properly added as key value pairs.

This is also in the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I read de docs but it seems that I missed that part. It works fine now. Thanks!